# Cross Thread Problem... Help Me

Tags: c#

i have 2 script 1- Soket.cs (Soket Server Working with thread) FormMain.cs(Working Normal) i call a function in FormMain from soket.cs with this code :

```
public void ResiveFunc(string FuncResive)
    {
        

        string FuncName = "";
        string FuncValue = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            FuncName += FuncResive[i];
        }
        for (int j = 4; j <= FuncResive.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            FuncValue += FuncResive[j];
        }
        MessageBox.Show(FuncName);
        MessageBox.Show(FuncValue);
        if (FuncName == "TAB")
        {
            Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
            mainForm.AdverFilter(FuncValue);
        }
        FuncName = "";
        FuncValue = "";
    }
```

i call this AdverFilter() function in FormMain :

```
public void AdverFilter(string value)
        {
            Messagebox.show(value);
            this.richTextBox1.Text = value;
        }
```

but its dont work!!! Messagebox show fine the value but richtextbox is null...
please tell me how can i fix this problem...!?

---

#### Update:

I changed my code to the following:

```
    public void AdverFilter(string value)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(AdverFilter),value);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(value);
            this.richTextBox1.Text = value;
        }

    }
```

This code has no syntax errors, but it still doesn't work.  I added `MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Text);` to this code.  It shows `true` but my Richtextbox is `null`.

Comment: when you breakpoint at the "This.richtTextBox1.Text = value;", does the value still have it's content ?

Comment: When you say richtextbox is null do you mean its value is empty or that the actual control is null (thus you're getting a null reference exception when trying to assign the value)?

Comment: I think is better to see the code you use to create the socket, accept the client and receive, and where you call it. It seems you are receiving the message before form initialization complete

Comment: Theun : when i check the richtextbox value in AdverFilter function the value is true , but when i check it from other object like Button the value is null...

Comment: Jorge : richtextbox.text == ""

Comment: Felice , can u see my code if i send it to your mail , i have only a few days to complete this project

Comment: @user584110: take note that this is a Q&A site, not a contact agency.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, that additional code cleared things a bit.

The callback is most likely done through ThreadPool and so the thread's apartment state is MTA. This is a problem because you are creating the form in the callback's thread and the forms require that the apartment state must be STA. Maybe you should create the form in the main thread and then use the ISynchronizeInvoke interface as shown by Fredrik Mörk.

PS. You should use System.String.Substring(...) to get the `FuncName` and `FuncValue`:

```
string FuncName = FuncResive.Substring(0, 3);
string FuncValue = FuncResive.Substring(4);
```

And why the `FuncName` and `FuncValue` values are set to empty string in the end? There is no reason for that.